# How to query child models from parent model data?

Tags: django, django-models, inheritance

I currently have a set of models like so:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    approved = models.BooleanField()

class ModelA(BaseModel):
    # model fields

class ModelB(BaseModel):
    # models fields

class ModelC(BaseModel):
    # model fields
```

What I'd like to do is get a list of all instances of `ModelA`, `ModelB`, and `ModelC` with `approved=True`.

I can query `BaseModel` with a queryset:

```
BaseModel.objects.filter(approved=True)
```

but this returns all instances of `BaseModel`, not `ModelA`, `ModelB`, or `ModelC`.  I'd like my queryset to contain instances of each model -- preferably without exhaustively querying every single possible child model of `BaseModel`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: this is what Django-polymorphic does, but model inheritance often is *not* a good idea: it will make a lot of JOINs making the query a lot more slow.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [**`django-polymorphic`** <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) does, but model inheritance often is *not* a good idea: it will make a lot of JOINs making the query a lot more slow.

Essentially what Django polymorphic will do is query with:

```
BaseModel.objects.filter(approved=True).select_related(
    'modela', 'modelb', 'modelc'
)
```

then it will look what JOIN was successful with:

```
for item in queryset:
    if hasattr(item, 'modela'):
        # use item.modela instead…
        pass
    if hasattr(item, 'modelb'):
        # use item.modelb instead…
        pass
    if hasattr(item, 'modelc'):
        # use item.modelc instead…
        pass
```

That being said, inheritance in *relational* databases is often *not* a good idea, and results in performance bottlenecks, but also in inconvenient querying. Therefore it might not be a good idea to use it anyway. Yes, Django implemented that, but probabably should be used as last resort.